# TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensor/Variables

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to convert a retrained version of MobileNet 0.50 using freeze_graph.py.

Here is my code.

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph --input_checkpoint=model.ckpt --input_graph=graph.pb --output_graph=frozen.pb --input_binary=TRUE --output_node_names=softmax
```

The input graph and checkpoint files have been obtained from retrain.py given by Tensorflow.

I've tried using .pbtxt, using the different checkpoint files outputed by saving the session, input_binary as false. I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?