# TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Same issue of these two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158636/typeerror-names-to-saveables-must-be-a-dict-mapping-string-names-to-tensor-vari)/[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837854/how-do-you-use-freeze-graph-py-in-tensorflow)). This is happening when I'm retrieving a TF model to display using [Lucid](https://github.com/tensorflow/lucid), following this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PPzeZi5sBN2YRlBmKsdvZPbfYtZI-pHl#scrollTo=LAw_5JBDE0wi). My full stack trace is:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/**init**.py:36:
>   FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from
>   `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated
>   as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.   from ._conv import
>   register_converters as _register_converters
>
> 2018-05-08
>   01:22:34.477907: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
>
> 2018-05-08
>   01:22:34.478221: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235 pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 totalMemory:
>   11.17GiB freeMemory: 362.12MiB
>
> 2018-05-08 01:22:34.478266: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible
>   gpu devices: 0 2018-05-08 01:22:34.871564: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:911] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2018-05-08
>   01:22:34.871635: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:917]      0 
>   2018-05-08 01:22:34.871680: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:930] 0:   N 
>   2018-05-08 01:22:34.871877: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
>   101 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus
>   id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7)
>
> Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 380, in 
>       app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 274, in main
>       FLAGS.saved_model_tags, checkpoint_version)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 256, in freeze_graph
>       checkpoint_version=checkpoint_version)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py",
>   line 130, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos
>       var_list=var_list, write_version=checkpoint_version)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1311, in **init**
>       self.build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1320, in build
>       self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1357, in _build
>       build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 787, in _build_internal
>       saveables = self._ValidateAndSliceInputs(names_to_saveables)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 688, in _ValidateAndSliceInputs
>       variable) **TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables.** Not a variable:
>   Tensor("conv2d_1/bias:0", shape=(16,), dtype=float32)

My network graph is defined as this:

> input_1
>
> conv2d_1/kernel
>
> conv2d_1/kernel/read
>
> conv2d_1/bias
>
> conv2d_1/bias/read
>
> conv2d_1/convolution
>
> conv2d_1/BiasAdd
>
> conv2d_1/Relu
>
> max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool
>
> conv2d_2/kernel
>
> conv2d_2/kernel/read
>
> conv2d_2/bias
>
> conv2d_2/bias/read
>
> conv2d_2/convolution
>
> conv2d_2/BiasAdd
>
> conv2d_2/Relu
>
> max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool
>
> conv2d_3/kernel
>
> conv2d_3/kernel/read
>
> conv2d_3/bias
>
> conv2d_3/bias/read
>
> conv2d_3/convolution
>
> conv2d_3/BiasAdd
>
> conv2d_3/Relu
>
> max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool
>
> conv2d_4/kernel
>
> conv2d_4/kernel/read
>
> conv2d_4/bias
>
> conv2d_4/bias/read
>
> conv2d_4/convolution
>
> conv2d_4/BiasAdd
>
> conv2d_4/Relu
>
> up_sampling2d_1/Shape
>
> up_sampling2d_1/strided_slice/stack
>
> up_sampling2d_1/strided_slice/stack_1
>
> up_sampling2d_1/strided_slice/stack_2
>
> up_sampling2d_1/strided_slice
>
> up_sampling2d_1/Const
>
> up_sampling2d_1/mul
>
> up_sampling2d_1/ResizeNearestNeighbor
>
> conv2d_5/kernel
>
> conv2d_5/kernel/read
>
> conv2d_5/bias
>
> conv2d_5/bias/read
>
> conv2d_5/convolution
>
> conv2d_5/BiasAdd
>
> conv2d_5/Relu
>   up_sampling2d_2/Shape up_sampling2d_2/strided_slice/stack
>
> up_sampling2d_2/strided_slice/stack_1
>
> up_sampling2d_2/strided_slice/stack_2 up_sampling2d_2/strided_slice
>
> up_sampling2d_2/Const up_sampling2d_2/mul
>
> up_sampling2d_2/ResizeNearestNeighbor conv2d_6/kernel
>
> conv2d_6/kernel/read conv2d_6/bias conv2d_6/bias/read
>
> conv2d_6/convolution conv2d_6/BiasAdd conv2d_6/Relu
>
> up_sampling2d_3/Shape up_sampling2d_3/strided_slice/stack
>
> up_sampling2d_3/strided_slice/stack_1
>
> up_sampling2d_3/strided_slice/stack_2 up_sampling2d_3/strided_slice
>
> up_sampling2d_3/Const up_sampling2d_3/mul
>
> up_sampling2d_3/ResizeNearestNeighbor conv2d_7/kernel
>
> conv2d_7/kernel/read conv2d_7/bias conv2d_7/bias/read
>
> conv2d_7/convolution conv2d_7/BiasAdd conv2d_7/Relu output_node0

Comment: How are you calling freeze_graph? And which TensorFlow version?